# Table or list: what should I use here?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, html-table

I would like to know which tags I should use for layout like this. Semantically is both a table and a list to me. How I can achieve those underlines and keep the markup right?

[image]

Comment: +1 for actually thinking this through

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would personally use an ordered list to achieve this, the sub list under Suma skladki means it isn't really tabular data.

This link should give you EXACTLY what you need:

http://thepcspy.com/read/css_table_of_contents/

Comment: `the sub list under Suma skladki means it isn't really tabular data` - disagree

Comment: Yeah vol7ron, I perhaps should have phrased that a little differently. The bullets suggest a list but it can be described either way. I think you'd struggle to achieve this cleanly with tables

Comment: `I think you'd struggle to achieve this cleanly with tables` absolutely agree, unless you use JavaScript to fill the cell, or possibly a div with a repeat-x, background image

Comment: This looks like a candidate for a definition list: http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/definition/

Answer (score 3):

To me personally, this looks more like a list than a table (though you could still construct it as a table, and do so justifiably). I would construct it as a nested list.

```
<ul>
  <li>Suma skladki <span class="price">900 PLN</span>
    <ul>
      <li>Skladka podstawawa 
          <span class="desc">(dia przychodu 250 000 PLN)</span> 
          <span class="price">550 PNL</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This will also give you more design flexibility in the future than if you use a `table` element. I'm not so sure a `table` communicates the nested hierarchy that you have here as well as a series of lists either.

Answer (score 1):

- Just because you have sub-data, does not mean it's a list; there are plenty of tables that have subcategories (just look at a general ledger)
- You have multiple pieces of structured information, arranged in a *consistent* way, which constitutes a table, or tabular data
- What you're showing above is the equivalent of a TOC (***Table*** of Contents) and it's a table for a reason (you have a label and a value)

That being said, this day in age it doesn't really matter what you use as long as you can defend it, especially since lists/divs can take on the shape of a table.

*It's more improper to use a `table` for something that is not a table, than to use a list for something that could use a table.*

Comment: "It's more improper to use a table for something that is not a table, than to use a list for something that could use a table." I am aware of this, but I hate trend that some people are trying to avoid tables for all cost, just misunderstanding idea of semantic design (e.g. using divs to draw table)

Comment: @SomalSomalski: I agree.  In fact, tables are really meaningful when it comes to Accessibility (508) and screen readers.  However there is a pretty hefty web cost; tables take longer to render and build in the DOM, which was a much bigger reason around the time when the whole Table vs Div debate was in focus.  That debate has kind of subsided, though we are discussing it here.

Comment: @SomalSomalski Regarding screen readers: unless you actually do test (& fix) the screen reader accessibility, your table may just be unreadable for a screen reader, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586478/tables-and-screen-readers