# Tables and Screen Readers

Tags: html, screen, accessibility, wcag2.0

I seem to be having troubles getting a screen reader to read simple tables. I have the HTML below:

```
<table alt="Account Information">
       <tr>
          <th scope='row'>Account Number:</th>
          <td>1111 1111 1111</td>
          <td>&nbsp&nbsp<td/>
          <th scope='row'>Reference Number:</th>
          <td>XXXX XXXX XXXX</td>
       </tr>
</table>
```

When the screen reader hits this table it says
"Table. 0 Columns. 0 Rows."

I have tried many examples online and tried to use that WCAG2.0 standards as a guide line, but it doesnt seem to work.

I have also tried different table layouts and structures and still get the same result.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why your headers and data are adjecent to each other?

Comment: @ShashankChaturvedi they are row headers and not column headers

Comment: Is that mean a single row, because you have just one row in there.

Comment: yes that is the way the information must be displayed

Comment: Have you tried replacing your table with an online example to see if that works? I read that the cells should not be empty so I would suggest removing the third cell and adding css to handle the whitespace. I also read that the table description can be in a `<caption>` tag just after the opening table tag instead of in alt. I doubt that would affect the reader but start with markup that works and gradually build on to it until you have your result. Just a guess but it could be that your reader is wonky.

Comment: @kleinkie it most likely is the screenreader, but part of the requirements state that it must also work with microsoft narrator as well as the major ones :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't run this through a screen reader, but it could be thrown off by your `&nbsp`. `&nbsp` needs to be closed with a semi-colon. Like this: `&nbsp;`. Also, there is no alt attribute for table. Provide an explanation, useful for screen readers, with the [summary attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H73.html) instead.

On top of that, I would advise that you remove that empty cell and make a bigger space with CSS.

1 - Remove the blank row and provide a gap with CSS, like this:

HTML

```
<table summary="Account Information">
   <tr>
      <th scope="row">Account Number:</th>
      <td>1111 1111 1111</td>

      <th scope="row">Reference Number:</th>
      <td>XXXX XXXX XXXX</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
th { padding: 0 10px;  }
```

2 - ...and on top of that, maybe it's a bit picky, so you could try:

```
<table summary="Account Information">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Account Number Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Account Number</th>
            <th scope="col">Reference Number Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Reference Number</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Account Number:</th>
            <td>1111 1111 1111</td>

            <th scope="row">Reference Number:</th>
            <td>XXXX XXXX XXXX</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
thead { display: none; }
th { padding: 0 10px;  }
```

3 - ...but ideally the table would be just like this:

```
<table summary="Account Information">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Account Number</th>
            <th scope="col">Reference Number</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1111 1111 1111</td>
            <td>XXXX XXXX XXXX</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
th { padding: 0 10px;  }
```

Comment: I was going to suggest adding `tbody` too, nice for at least mentioning that!

Comment: @SaggingRufus have any of these examples worked for you?

Comment: The final example is as you say the ideal one :) Just one thing.. there is no alt attribute for the table element, but you can use the summary attribute for summarizing the data and use the `caption` element to describe what the table is about.

Comment: Adding `thead` and then hiding it with `display:none` is kinda pointless (example 2) as screen readers will not announce it.